# To be able to cntrl-drag a segue between a view to a storyboard scene, what are the preconditions

Tags: ios, storyboard, interface-builder, xcode7

I know I can ctrl-drag a segue from a UIButton to a scene, or from a UITableViewCell; but if I try to ctrl-drag from UIView, the drag destination scene doesn't 'light up,' and so I find I'm unable to create such a segue. I feel like I'm missing something basic here; or, perhaps this isn't possible? So: How do I create a segue between a view and a scene?

(In order to be crystal clear: this question is in the context of my trying to understand, generally, between what kinds of 'things' in a storyboard is it possible to ctrl-drag a segue.)

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be an interactive item, like a button because you can tap it, same for a cell. If you want to be able to tap a plain `UIView` (or simple subclass) you should add a tap gesture recogniser to it and connect the segue to that.

Note that a segue dragged from the view controller to another view controller isn't triggered by any tap, it's to be triggered from code.

Comment: I wonder what exactly makes a button or a gesture recognizer an "interactive item," and why a UIView can't be one. That is what I'd like to discover. It's a good suggestion, to add a tap gesture recognizer to the UIView; but I'd like to avoid that overhead.

Comment: UIView isn't a subclass of UIControl, that's the difference. I don't know if IB requires something else that you'd need to add in a custom class but the control class adds all the target / action logic.

Answer (score 0):

Any UIKit element that inherits from UIControl can be used as ctrl+drag segue origin point.

For your case, as @Wain suggested, you can use a tap gesture recogniser as the origin of the segue.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I created a UIControl subclass and wasn't able to ctrl+drag from it.